# Working with the SEC Edgar Logfile database // ZIP file extraction and storing of large databases

Tags: python, stored-procedures, bigdata, zip

Working with the SEC Edgar Lofgile database I face a couple of challenges. (https://www.sec.gov/dera/data/edgar-log-file-data-set.html)

My job is to download the data step by step and then assign the various IP addresses to the companies. Using a combination of WRDS, the ARIN Bulk Whois database, and string matching, I was able to match companies to IP addresses.

The individual data sets are stored in a zip file. Currently I use the following code to unzip the files, which is slow and takes up a lot of memory:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

#last day of the database
html = 'http://www.sec.gov/dera/data/Public-EDGAR-log-file-data/2017/Qtr2/log20170630.zip'

def get_df(html):
    #open zipfile via requests/BytesIO/ZipFile
    r_zip = requests.get(html)
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(r_zip.content))
    files = zip_file.namelist()
    #read zip as DataFrame
    with zip_file.open(files[0]) as log:
        data = pd.read_csv(log)
```

After the extraction, I analyze the record (groupby companies, etc.) and save the result in a csv file. However, the result of my analysis is still so big that downloading the whole database of SEC Edgar logfiles is difficult.

1. Does anyone know a faster and more memory friendly way to download
   the database?
2. Does anyone have an idea how to save the
   result so that working with the whole database is possible?

Answer (score 0):

After extracting each csv file, upload the data into SQL and then, delete the csv file.

Comment: Answer is way to short, this is more a hint than a proper and complete answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31233130)